# How to draw the skeleton from the available coordinates?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect.toolbox

as i typed in the question, i want to draw the skeletons-line (or draw the line between two points ) from the available coordinates. After drawing, the completed manual-skeleton will look like this. It draw as same as Skeleton Basic did, but the coordinates provided by us.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/425774

I saved the coordinates of joints in a text file and this application will take the data from this file to draw. Can anyone please help me ? I really need it.

I did like this but the skeleton on the screen was freezed, it didn't move follow the coordinates from the text file.

```
FileStream fs;
    private void Model_DrawBoneAndJoints(ref Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        fs = new FileStream
            (@"C:\Users\PhucTruongTien\Desktop\datagram.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        float[] x = new float[20];
        float[] y = new float[20];

        SkeletonPoint position;
        Array Joint_Types = Enum.GetValues(typeof(JointType));
        //Joint[] joint_array = new Joint[20];

        foreach (JointType j_types in Joint_Types)
        {
            Joint joint = new Joint();
            joint = skeleton.Joints[j_types];
            joint.TrackingState = JointTrackingState.Tracked;
            position = joint.Position;
            position.X = (float)Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
            position.Y = (float)Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
            position.Z = (float)Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
            joint.Position = position;
            skeleton.Joints[j_types] = joint;
        }
```

}

private void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
        Model_DrawBoneAndJoints(ref skeleton, drawingContext);

```
        //i++;
        // Render Torso
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Spine);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Spine, JointType.HipCenter);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight);

        // Left Arm
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft);

        // Right Arm
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight);

        // Left Leg
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft);

        // Right Leg
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight);
        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight);

        this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight);

        // Render Joints
        foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
        {
            Brush drawBrush = null;

            if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;
            }
            else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
            {
                drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;
            }

            if (drawBrush != null)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint.Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: When you read always the same file with the same coordinates of a single skeleton, what should produce a motion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StreamWriter`, initialize it at the selected path, then for each frame, increase the frame counter, write it to the file, write the timestamp to the file, then loop through the joints and write them to the file. I would do this as follows:

```
using System.IO;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@path);
int frames = 0;

...

void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    frames++;
    using (SkeletonFrame sFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrameData())
    {
        if (sFrame == null)
            return;

        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

        Skeleton skeleton = (from s in skeletons
                                where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                                select s);
        if (skeleton == null)
            return;

        if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
            {
                writer.Write(joint.Position.X + "," + joint.Position.Y + "," joint.Position.Z + ",");
            }
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to read from the file:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@path);
int frame = -1;
JointCollection joints;

...

string[] lines = reader.ReadAllLines();

...

void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    canvas.Children.Clear();
    string[] coords = lines[frame];
    int jointIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < coords.Length; i += 3)
    {
        joints[jointIndex].Position.X = int.Parse(coords[i]);
        joints[jointIndex].Position.Y = int.Parse(coords[i + 1]);
        joints[jointIndex].Position.X = int.Parse(coords[i + 2]);
        jointIndex++;
    }

    DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame();
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.Spine, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Head }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft }, depthFrame, canvas));
    canvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(joints, brush, new JointType[] { JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight }, depthFrame, canvas));
    depthFrame.Dispose();

    frame++;
}

Point GetDisplayPosition(Joint joint, DepthImageFrame depthFrame, Canvas skeleton)
{
    float depthX, depthY;
    KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
    DepthImageFormat depthImageFormat = sensor.DepthStream.Format;
    DepthImagePoint depthPoint = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(joint.Position, depthImageFormat);

    depthX = depthPoint.X;
    depthY = depthPoint.Y;

    depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));
    depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));

    int colorX, colorY;
    ColorImagePoint colorPoint = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthPointToColorPoint(depthImageFormat, depthPoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
    colorX = colorPoint.X;
    colorY = colorPoint.Y;

    return new System.Windows.Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
}

Polyline GetBodySegment(Joint[] joints, Brush brush, JointType[] ids, DepthImageFrame depthFrame, Canvas canvas)
{
    PointCollection points = new PointCollection(ids.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; ++i)
    {
        points.Add(GetDisplayPosition(joints[i], depthFrame, canvas));
    }
    Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
    polyline.Points = points;
    polyline.Stroke = brush;
    polyline.StrokeThickness = 5;
    return polyline;
}
```

While what you are doing will work, when I have done this in the past I have used this sort of methodology described. Another way to do it with a similar setup you are doing to the amount of frames at the top, write every joint to a line, then have a multidimensional array that (eg. `jointCoords = new string[amountOfFrames, 21, 3]`), then every frame increase the frame counter, and go through all the joints, and then their x, y, and z. An example of reading from the file then would look like

```
        char[] delimiters = new char[] { '|', ' ' };
        //Make sure this file exists.
        string file_name_2 = "C:\\path\\doctor.txt";
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@file_name_2);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {

            // for the skeleton frame

            string[] seperated = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            seperated.CopyTo(delim, 0);
            skeleton_frames_doctor[total_frames, count, 0] = int.Parse(delim[0]);
            skeleton_frames_doctor[total_frames, count, 1] = int.Parse(delim[1]);
            skeleton_frames_doctor[total_frames, count, 2] = int.Parse(delim[2]);
            count++;

            if (count == 21)
            {
                count = 0;
                total_frames++;
            }

        }
```

And to read would look something like:

```
                foreach (Joint joint in data.Joints)
                {

                         Point jointPos = getDisplayPosition(joint);

                        //storing the patients x y coordinates
                        skeleton_frames[totalFrames1, joint_count, 0] = (double)jointPos.X;
                        skeleton_frames[totalFrames1, joint_count, 1] = (double)jointPos.Y;

                        //getting the doctors x y coordinates
                        XPos = (skeleton_frames[totalFrames1, 0, 0]) - (skeleton_frames_doctor[totalFrames1, 0, 0]);
                        YPos = (skeleton_frames[totalFrames1, 0, 1]) - (skeleton_frames_doctor[totalFrames1, 0, 1]);

                        //Scaling and transformation of doctors frame to patients frame
                        skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, joint_count, 0] = skeleton_frames_doctor[totalFrames1, joint_count, 0] + XPos;
                        skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, joint_count, 1] =  skeleton_frames_doctor[totalFrames1, joint_count, 1] + YPos;
                        for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++)
                        {
                            double DistP = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((skeleton_frames[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 0] - 1, 0]) - skeleton_frames[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 1] - 1, 0], 2) + Math.Pow((skeleton_frames[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 0] - 1, 1]) - skeleton_frames[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 1] - 1, 1], 2));
                            double DistD = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 0] - 1, 0]) - skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 1] - 1, 0], 2) + Math.Pow((skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 0] - 1, 1]) - skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 1] - 1, 1], 2));
                            double alpha = DistP / DistD;
                            skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 1]-1, 0] = skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 0]-1, 0] + (skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 1]-1, 0] - skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 0]-1, 0]) * (alpha);
                            skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 1]-1, 1] = skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 0]-1, 1] + (skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 1]-1, 1] - skeleton_frames_doctor_new[totalFrames1, JointNo[j, 0]-1, 1]) * (alpha);
                        }


                    Line jointLine = new Line();
                    jointLine.X1 = jointPos.X - 3;
                    jointLine.X2 = jointLine.X1 + 6;
                    jointLine.Y1 = jointLine.Y2 = jointPos.Y;
                    jointLine.Stroke = jointColors[joint.ID];
                    jointLine.StrokeThickness = 6;
                    skeleton.Children.Add(jointLine);
                    joint_count++;
                }
```

Note that `JointNo` is just an array that is used to find the index of certain joint types. Here it is

```
        int[,] JointNo = new int[19, 2];

        JointNo[0, 0] = 1;
        JointNo[0, 1] = 2;
        JointNo[1, 0] = 2;
        JointNo[1, 1] = 3;
        JointNo[2, 0] = 3;
        JointNo[2, 1] = 4;
        JointNo[3, 0] = 3;
        JointNo[3, 1] = 9;
        JointNo[4, 0] = 9;
        JointNo[4, 1] = 10;
        JointNo[5, 0] = 10;
        JointNo[5, 1] = 11;
        JointNo[6, 0] = 11;
        JointNo[6, 1] = 12;
        JointNo[7, 0] = 3;
        JointNo[7, 1] = 5;
        JointNo[8, 0] = 5;
        JointNo[8, 1] = 6;
        JointNo[9, 0] = 6;
        JointNo[9, 1] = 7;
        JointNo[10, 0] = 7;
        JointNo[10, 1] = 8;
        JointNo[11, 0] = 1;
        JointNo[11,1] = 13;
        JointNo[12, 0] = 13;
        JointNo[12, 1] = 14;
        JointNo[13,0] = 14;
        JointNo[13, 1] = 15;
        JointNo[14, 0] = 15;
        JointNo[14, 1] = 16;
        JointNo[15, 0] = 1;
        JointNo[15, 1] = 17;
        JointNo[16, 0] = 17;
        JointNo[16, 1] = 18;
        JointNo[17, 0] = 18;
        JointNo[17, 1] = 19;
        JointNo[18, 0] = 19;
        JointNo[18, 1] = 20;
```

You could see this all in action from [this code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3094052) which was written in beta 2, so it will not compile currently but it is mostly the methodology you should be concerned with.

Comment: Thank you, i worked and i have one more question, how to change the color of the skeleton from green to red in kinect ?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 You change `brush`

Comment: Thank you ! Can you give me your e-mail or your facebook ?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 If this solved the question, accept it, and you can try to start a chat with me sometime

Comment: i am having a lot of questions, so, if i can start a chat with you, the problem will be solved easier

Comment: @iamatsundere181 Yes, I can talk in a few hours or email me outlawlemur@gmail . com